# Using cast when joining tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, indexing

I am using a legacy database at my job and I need to join two tables on columns which are different data types.

One is int and the other one is long, so when Entity framework translates `LINQ` join to `SQL` expression I got something like this in `JOIN` condition: `CAST( [Extent1].[KundeID] AS bigint) = [Extent2].[ClientNumber]`.

Because of this, index on `KundeID` columd is ignored and joining is very slow.

Is it possible to create and index on casted value, so I have index on `CAST( [KundeID] AS bigint)` instead of `[KundeID]`? Or any other solution that might work..

Comment: Have you tried storing the converted column as a computed column? That way you could add an index to that column. More info on MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try applying `Convert.ToInt32()` on `[Extent2].[ClientNumber]` so the index can be used?

Comment: I have indexes on both columns. So none of them should be converted.

Comment: Then I think you need to add a the computer column and index as suggested above.